# Window File Batch Rename - keep only last 8 caracters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to use a batch to rename a file from
"Rapp_20220628150328_001.tif"
to "Rapp_YYYY_MM_GG_001.tif"

adding "Rap_" and the date is not a problem, but I don't understand how to keep the last 8 characters "_001.tif"

thanks in advance

Comment: If you show us your code by including it into your question using the `edit` button, then we'd be able to see where the required data is stored which might save a deal of unnecessary work. In short, `%filename:~-8` is how. Using that method within your code - that's another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

For renaming the files

```
Rapp_20220628150328_001.tif
Rapp_20220628150436_002.tif
```

in the current directory to

```
Rapp_2022_06_28_001.tif
Rapp_2022_06_28_002.tif
```

would be needed only a batch file with the following command lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%I in ('dir "Rapp_*_*.tif" /B') do (
    set "FileName=%%I"
    ren "%%I" "!FileName:~0,9!_!FileName:~9,2!_!FileName:~11,2!!FileName:~19!"
)
endlocal
```

But that simple solution does not work for a directory with the following files:

```
Image_1.Develop & Test(!)_100%_2022-06-27_01.tif
Image_1.Develop & Test(!)_100%_20220628150328_02.tif
Rapp_2022-06-27_001.tif
Rapp_20220628150328_003.tif
Rapp_20220628150436_002.tif
```

The file names in this directory should be named finally:

```
Image_1.Develop & Test(!)_100%_2022-06-27_01.tif
Image_1.Develop & Test(!)_100%_2022_06_28_02.tif
Rapp_2022-06-27_001.tif
Rapp_2022_06_28_002.tif
Rapp_2022_06_28_003.tif
```

There are following criteria to take into account:

1. The length of the part left to date/time in file name in format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` is variable.
2. The part left to date/time in file name can have multiple underscores.
3. The file name can contain characters with a special meaning for the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` on processing a batch file even on being enclosed in double quotes like `!` and `%`.
4. The number of digits in file name left to the  file extension is variable, too.
5. There are files in the directory which have already the wanted format.

In this case the solution with a batch file requires a more complex code like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion DisableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "*_*_*.*" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "_[12][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][01][0123456789][0123][0123456789][012][0123456789][012345][0123456789][012345][0123456789]_"') do set "FileName=%%~nI" & call :RenameFile "%%~xI") & goto EndBatch
:RenameFile
set "ModifiedName=%FileName:.=|%
for %%J in ("%ModifiedName:_=.%") do set "FileNumber=%%~xJ" & for %%K in ("%%~nJ") do set "DateTime=%%~xK" & set "FirstPart=%%~nK"
set "FirstPart=%FirstPart:.=_%"
ren "%FileName%%~1" "%FirstPart:|=.%_%DateTime:~1,4%_%DateTime:~5,2%_%DateTime:~7,2%_%FileNumber:~1%%~1"
goto :EOF
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

This universal solution is slower than the simple solution on execution, but it really works as long as the file names end with `_yyyyMMddHHmmss_n.*` whereby `n` is a number with one or more digits. The number is not verified by the regular expression as the search string would become too long for **FINDSTR**.

Both batch files do not handle the use case that a file should be renamed to a name which another file or directory has already in the current directory. It does also not handle the use case that the file rename fails because of the file is currently opened by an application with shared access denied for other processes.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cmd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `|` and `2>nul`. The redirection operators `|` and `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with `dir` and `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background with option `/c` and the command line appended as additional arguments.

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&` on being found in a command line outside a double quoted argument string and also not escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal character.